# Append XSLT Stylesheet to XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, append

I want to attach my XSLT stylesheet to my XML document that I created.

### XML Document Code

XML document is created using the following code:

```
Private Sub CreateXML(ByVal ds1 As StatusProd.dsAssemblies, ByVal ReportName As String)
    ReportName = ReportName.Replace(".rdlc", "")
    Dim w As New XmlTextWriter(ReportName & ".xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    w.WriteStartDocument(True) 'Start document
    w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    w.Indentation = 2

    w.WriteStartElement("Table") 'Start table
    For Each row As DataRow In ds1.Tables(0).Rows
        w.WriteStartElement("Assemblies")
        w.WriteStartElement("MachineNo")
        w.WriteString(row(0))
        w.WriteEndElement()

        w.WriteStartElement("Description")
        w.WriteString(row(1))
        w.WriteEndElement()

        w.WriteStartElement("Client")
        w.WriteString(row(2))
        w.WriteEndElement()

        w.WriteStartElement("DateTransfer")
        w.WriteString(row(4))
        w.WriteEndElement()
        w.WriteEndElement()
    Next

    w.WriteEndElement() 'End table
    w.WriteEndDocument() 'End document
    w.Close()
End Sub
```

---

### XSLT Append to XML

I tried adding the following code at the end of my XML Document creator and got the error:  **could not insert the node at the specified location**.

```
'Append XSL to XML
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("rptStatusProd.xml")
doc.PrependChild(doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Fetch.xslt'"))
doc.Save(w)
```

---

### Final XML Doc Result

I want to add my processing instruction in the second line of my XML document, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Fetch.xslt"?>
```

I've been trying to reproduce this:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Comment: Whereabouts in your XML are you trying to add the processing instruction?  And to which XML - the XMLTextWriter or the xml loaded from rptStatusProd.xml?  The prepend is not working on doc because the Load will add an xml declaration at the beginning of doc and I believe you cannot put a processing instruction before the xml declaration.

Comment: @alergy I updated where I'm trying to add the processing instruction. Initially I would have liked to add it directly to the XmlTextWriter, saving me some space. But I was trying something else and decided to load the rptStatusProd.xml file, and re-save everything afterwards

Comment: The problem you have though is still that rptStatusProd.xml will be appended to XmlTextWriter output i.e. after `</Table>` you will get `<?xml...` - out of interest why can't you call `w.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Fetch.xslt'")`?  I know you said you took a different direction, but it would seem that that would be the way to get what you are aiming for.

Comment: @alergy Hey, nvm what I said before. I tried it a little differently and it worked. If you want to post it as an answer I'll gladly upvote & accept it. Worked flawlessly. As for all the other answers, I appreciate the help and your answers were definatly worth the upvote. Thank you!

Comment: glad to help - I've combined my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepend is not working on doc because the `Load` will add an xml declaration at the beginning of doc and I believe you cannot put a processing instruction before the xml declaration.

The other problem you may have is that rptStatusProd.xml will be appended to XmlTextWriter output i.e. after `</Table>` you will get `<?xml...` - you could call this:

`w.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Fetch.xslt'")`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
doc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Fetch.xslt'"))
```

You cannot prepend anything to the document root. You can prepend something to the document element though.

Comment: I'm having an issue with my `doc.Load("rptStatusProd.xml)`. Apparently it is being used by another process... I'm trying to figure out how to kill that process in order to try your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

By attempting to prepend, you're clashing with the header node; instead of prepending, use [`InsertAfter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter.aspx):

```
XmlProcessingInstruction pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Fetch.xslt'");
doc.InsertAfter(pi, doc.FirstChild);
```